# Wordpress SSL switch/rewrite base on request (fixing insecure content)

Tags: ssl, rewrite, https, wordpress

I have a small Wordpress site to share my hobby. My webhost is SSL enabled and I successfully set the "force SSL login" option. But because I started without SSL there are mixed protocols in the source and my viewers get "insecure content" warnings.

What I want:

- Viewer A visits "http://example.com", all URLs use "HTTP"
- Viewer B visits "http**s**://example.com", all URLS use "HTTP**s**"

Basically, wordpress should detect if the viewer wants to use SSL or not and change the URLs/Links accordingly.

What I get:

I can't find any setting or plugin to do that. Every tutorial or plugin assumes you want to enforce SSL. Which I don't want because it slows the page down and increases CPU load.

Do you know a good plugin -or- can you convince me to enforce SSL?

Comment: I've done this a few times before, and basically the only answer I ever came up with was to rewrite the content myself. And, no, enforcing SSL doesn't have any significant effect on page load time or CPU. In fact if you've set up SPDY or HTTP2 then it's usually faster.

Comment: "SSL doesn't have any significant effect on page load time or CPU"...particularly on a personal hobby site that likely gets very low traffic (if you'll forgive my assumption).

Comment: Ideally you will want to tell WordPress to use 'relative links' for assets and pages rather than absolute. The only time I have SSL issues with WordPress is when there's an SSL terminated load balancer. Could you try a plugin that switches to relative links? Something like - https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

Answer (score 0):

You can go through your content, find all links, hrefs etc. and instead of writing http://path/file.ext or https:// you just write //path/file.ext

Any modern browsers will then fill in the schema by themselves, depending on the URL accessed.

They are called schemaless URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481193/how-safe-is-it-to-use-domain-com-schema-less-links

Not sure whether there is a plugin to do this for you.

If you happen to run Nginx, you can run a string replace on every request too. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html for details. It would look like:

```
location / {
    sub_filter 'http://'  '//';
    sub_filter 'https://' '//';
}
```

There's more than one way to achieve the logistics of converting your URLs.